# Should I vote to reopen when I believe the reason for closing no longer applies?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

When browsing the reopen queue, I often find questions closed as *too broad* or *unclear what you're asking* that were afterwards edited.

Let's say that *from my point of view*, the question is indeed improved in that regard. However, I may not have enough expertise on the subject to determine if it can indeed "be answered in a few paragraphs", or if it is still an inappropriate question for another reason. Therefore, I could:

- **Vote to reopen.** To the best of my knowledge, I believe the reason for closing no longer applies, so it should be given a new chance.
- **Skip.** I don't know enough about the topic to know *for sure* that it's a good question now. Better to leave that decision for an expert.

What do you think should be the correct action in that case? Because both options seem to have some justification.

Comment: There is no shame in skipping if you are unsure.

Comment: For having several topic being put on hold and never reopened even after I edited those several times, I beg you, if you think the edit is constructive, please vote to reopen. It is not like something horrible would happen if you make a mistake. Plus I don't think everybody that vote to put on hold actually know a lot about the topic. Most are just chain reviewers who actually read only the title and judge based on their general feeling

Comment: Absolutely. If you believe that the reason no longer applies you have to vote for reopening, otherwise reopening doesn't make sense at all. If you are not sure, skip it. Btw. do you think the guys who vote for closing are absolutely sure? They never are. The question is probably if you believe that it should be closed for another reason?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The short answer is, vote to reopen if you think the question should be open. If you *don't* think it should be open, then don't vote to reopen it.

There is an exception to the above rule: If a question is closed as a duplicate, and it's not actually a duplicate, then vote to reopen, and go have a beer.

If you prefer pictures, I made up [a handy flow-chart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216755/reopen-minimal-understanding-questions/216761#216761) for your benefit:

### Should I re-open a closed question?

[image: a flowchart]

Comment: The point I was trying to make was that I'm not exactly sure if it's useful, but it sure looks like the old reason for closing no longer applies. Is that _enough_ to vote to reopen? Is it _more useful_ to vote or leave as is in those cases? Plus, this flowchart needs a new end state for non-beer-drinkers :)

Comment: What matters is that questions which can be answered effectively are open, and those that can't are closed. The reasons are intended to guide both closers and askers, but comments can do just as well if that's all that's lacking; by and large, closed is closed regardless of reason. Substitute tea for beer if you prefer.

Comment: I'm at work. Do I always *have to* get a beer at the end? That may cause problems. And many new bug reports I'll have to close later.

Comment: @deceze If you carefully measure your beer intake, you may find a [massive increase in productivity instead](http://xkcd.com/323/).

Comment: The short answer is inconsistent with the diagram. According to the short answer, a question that is closed as duplicate, but it's not actually a duplicate, but consists of multiple distinct questions, **should not** be voted for reopen. According to the diagram, **it should**. Since a long answer is missing, should I assume that the diagram constitutes the long answer, and resolve the inconsistency in favor of the diagram?

Comment: If you're in a hurry, use the short answer @theodor; if you got time, use the flowchart.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for the clarification. This suits me well, because I am never in hurry, so I'll always use the chart. Meaning that I will continue casting reopen votes to questions that I believe that were closed for the wrong reason (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762931/why-parallel-foreach-worked-but-creating-multiple-task-didnt) one).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias than we are in agreement - you edit the question you've linked to and I remove my duplicate vote (because post with two questions is not on-topic, clearly-written).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would like to, but unfortunately I can't edit the post without guessing which of the two presented questions is more important for the OP, so that I can remove the other one. If I was allowed to guess, I would probably remove the second question (the duplicate one).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias your call. It's easy to move duplicate one out and convert it to a comment so OP still have access to link... Unfortunately you've already commented that you can't make first one on-topic easily :) " We can't really tell which version should be faster without knowing what code is running." - you'd have to do more guessing and demonstrate research so remaining  part of the post looks like a solid on-topic non-opinion based question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov indeed. I am not generally opposed at closing problematic questions (although I would prefer if the closing action was delayed for some hours after the initial post), but I see a problem with closing a question for an incorrect reason. It doesn't point the OP to the right direction regarding improving their question (or deleting it and making a better one). They may become confused and abandon the question without feedback. As for the specific question, I don't think that it can be improved without feedback from the OP.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias totally fair - sometimes I don't follow my own rules. I know that I should have downvote as "unclear" and VTC as "needs details"... too late now as I spent my close vote on that post already.

Comment: @Shog9 if you don't mind I added an extra line of text under the short answer, to make the text more consistent with the diagram.

Comment: "There is an exception to the above rule: If a question is closed as a duplicate, and it's not actually a duplicate, then vote to reopen, and go have a beer." I have been cautioned against reopening questions that were improperly closed as a duplicate but should be closed and deleted for a different reason, because it makes it harder to get the question closed and deleted.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it takes only one gold badger to close a question as duplicate, but three votes are required for closing it for any other reason. Which makes it reasonable to revert an incorrect closure as duplicate, by another gold badger who has this privilege, in order to enable the proper democratic procedures. Otherwise it gives the incentive to gold badgers who think that a question should be closed for a X reason, to abuse their power and close it single-handedly as a duplicate of a random semi-related question. This is not theoretical. I have witnessed it happening many times.

Comment: Couple notes, @karl: 1) if a post should and can be deleted, delete it and then we can avoid worrying about closing. 2) this also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links

Comment: I know about editing duplicate links, and have been doing a lot of it lately. However, sometimes there is something that was quite lazily hammered but was really caused by a typo. I would love to delete these things, but it generally requires two more votes plus other conditions.

Answer (score -2):

Everywhere you turn in Stack Overflow, you are encouraged to edit your question to make it better rather than ask a new one.  If editing the question doesn't result in *somebody* voting to reopen, it makes a mockery of that advice.  I'd say if you're on the fence about voting to reopen, go ahead and reopen.