# Should I reopen questions that already have a good answer?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I have come across a question that was closed (i.e. put on hold as "unclear" by 5 people) very quickly after it was asked. Fortunately for the OP, some people were quick enough to answer it before it was closed.

I think that the 5 people are wrong, and the question is in fact very clear, so maybe I should vote to reopen it (as described in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262212/509868) post).

However, why bother? OP got their answer; everyone is happy.

However, this looks bad to a casual visitor who comes here through a google (closed question - is OP guilty of something?). In addition, the question was also downvoted (in my opinion, incorrectly) - does it mean that it will be deleted soon, unless it's reopened?

So, should I vote "reopen" in this situation?

P.S. here is the question (please note that I edited it after all the stuff described above took place):

[What is the precedence of the ! operator vs -- in the expression !x--?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24785272/509868)

Comment: Can you post a link to the question? It is odd that 5 people are wrong and you are so sure not to be

Comment: You should judge a question on its own merits, as if there aren't any answers or comments (although the latter could serve to highlight flaws, if there are any). If the question is clear, then it shouldn't be closed as unclear. The presence of answers shouldn't affect that decision. And I'm not sure about the deletion criteria; I know downvoted/closed questions without answers are deleted, but I'm not sure about what would happen if upvoted answers are present.

Comment: @user3580294 You are correct that answers don't affect whether or not a question should be closed, but they do indeed become a consideration when considering whether a question should be deleted.  A question should only be deleted if there isn't value in keeping any of the content in the question or any answers around.

Comment: Well, it's a really bad question either way.  The user is basically just asking for users to regurgitate the documentation for two different operators.  That's not a question that belongs on SO.

Comment: @Servy I don't think it's a "I am lazy" question. The code there is a combination of 3 aspects (`if` without a comparison inside; `logical-not` on an integer; post-decrement) which are tricky by themselves; even more so when combined. There is no chance OP could just go RTFM and come up with a correct understanding. In addition, that seems to be pretty idiomatic code, so it's likely to help future visitors.

Comment: @anatolyg Each of those three things are separate things that should be researched, will likely result in the answer being found, and that, individually, could possibly be an appropriate question if there are no existing resources on each topic (which I would be shocked to find being the case).  Putting them together in no way makes any of those operations any more complex.  You absolutely *can* RTFM for each operation and come up with the correct answer.  **That's how programming works**.  You focus on understanding each piece, and when you do, it comes together easy.

Comment: @anatolyg   You don't learn what sequences of several operators do as a group, in the same way that rather than trying to memorize the meaning of every single phrase in the English language, it's easier to understand what individual words mean and then learn how to put multiple words together to make up a phrase.  On top of that, this is almost certainly not going to help any future visitors.  Do you really think people are going to google `if (!si--)`?  They won't use a different variable name?  Questions of the form "`<code block>` explain" are almost impossible to help anyone else.

Comment: @user3580294, the problem has to do with the closing reason: a question that has two valid answers cannot be completely unclear. "Unclear" seems to be a common closing reason for reviewers who really don't make any effort to try to understand the question. (This might not be the case for this question, since it was initially rather badly formatted. I'm not sure when the all votes were cast.)

Comment: @Servy, the point of SO is to avoid RTFM, at the very least when a problem is addressed in multiple parts of the manual. Otherwise, we'd just write link-only answers all day.

Comment: @Bruno The expectation is that questions authors should be doing research before asking questions, and that they shouldn't be asking questions to begin with that would have been answered by simply glancing at the documentation for the topics in question.  Questions like this *shouldn't be on the site in the first place*.

Comment: @Servy, knowing what to look for in the manual (and surely there's more than one book on C++) is always easier when you have more experience. Easy questions have their place on SO. While I agree showing evidence of some research is much better, it's hard to show much here, since visibly the asker had no idea where to start. We were all beginners once.

Comment: @Bruno A question being easy is indeed not a reason to prohibit it.  The fact that the person made zero effort to research the question, even doing the most basic of tasks such as looking at the documentation for the operation(s) that he didn't understand, *is* a reason for a question to not belong on the site.  Yes, were were all beginners once, and that doesn't mean that it's appropriate to ask zero effort/zero research questions on SO.

Comment: After improving edit this question is now a top 10% of clearest question on SO.

Comment: Funny thing is that both answers contradict each other (or am I wrong and it is too late for me).

Comment: The original question was pretty unclear if you asked me. "How if does it work?" does not tell me what the problem/question really is. In its current form, I would *still* downvote it for lacking research, but it should definitely remain open.

Comment: @Bruno The presence of answers themselves doesn't indicate clearness;  it's possible for several contradictory answers to exist, each being "valid" for a particular interpretation of the question (although I don't think it's the case for this particular question). I'm not sure what the close voters thought when they closed the question; although it took me several reads, I was eventually able to figure something out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should vote for reopen a question whenever the question is worth to be open regardless of if there are answers or not and how good they are.

- Even the best answers may not be found if the question is badly posed.
- If the answer is really good there probably is a really good question either already existing or wanting to be asked.

Comment: Sidenote, you should also consider the possibility that the quesiton was closed for the wrong reason. Perhaps the question is also a duplicate for example. In that case it should NOT get reopened.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I think this was discussed somewhere else in the last days on meta. Someone said that the exact close reason doesn't matter so much - if it should be closed you should vote for it to be closed. Of course it would be even better if the right close reason (duplicate for example) is displayed. "Worth to be open" in my eyes already includes that it should not be a duplicate.

Comment: I know your answer already implies mine (Thats why I voted it up), just wanted to emphasize this point.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if a question deserves to be open, you should vote to reopen it. The reason is that that closed questions are subject to deletion, either automatically by a script, or manually by 10K users.

Even more so if the question has good answers. We don't want good answers to end up deleted, because a question is erroneously closed.

The specific example however is probably not worth reopening, as the asker is essentially asking two questions at once (the meaning of the `--` operator, and the behavior of the if with an `int` condition), making the question too broad.

Comment: If a question that asks to explain a single line of code that fits in 10 characters is too broad, I wonder what your definition of a question that is "too localised" is.