# Should I vote to reopen questions that are closed for the wrong reason?

Tags: discussion, support

Sometimes when I'm reviewing the reopen queue, I see questions that are closed for being unclear. When I read the question I understand the problem perfectly, but I can also see that it is to broad, off topic or something else. In short, it should be closed, but not for the reason that it was closed for.

Should I just press "leave closed" or should I vote to reopen it so that it can be reclosed with the correct reason?

(Maybe it would be an idea to have a "reclose" button in the reopen queue so you can instantly vote to change the reason without reopening)

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because it refers to unedited questions. The [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262211/should-i-vote-to-reopen-when-i-believe-the-reason-for-closing-no-longer-applies) is about edited questions.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias But the answer to that question applies equally here, even if the question itself is a slightly different situation.

Comment: @John Montgomery I agree that the answer to that question is applicable here, because it answers the general case. But that question is restrictive, and this creates a problem because I may want to offer a different perspective to the general case, but I can't do it there because my answer would be off topic. The correct place to post my answer would be here, because this question is not restrictive, but I can't because it's closed.