# Re-open closed question with incorrect answer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

#### Background

I recently had a problem where I needed to add a user label to optimized code and I found this post:
[Volatile labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278400/volatile-labels)

The accepted answer states that it is not possible.
After a couple hours trying different ways to debug my problem I searched again (with different search terms) where I found this other post and answer: [How to tell gcc to keep my unused labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086938/how-to-tell-gcc-to-keep-my-unused-labels)
which gives a solution to the problem.

#### Question

I want to re-open [Volatile labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278400/volatile-labels) and provide an answer (or at least mark it as a duplicate of [How to tell gcc to keep my unused labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086938/how-to-tell-gcc-to-keep-my-unused-labels)) because the currently accepted answer is wrong.

#### Already Tried

[I already tried to edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19278400/2) to resolve the original close reason in an attempt to re-open it such that I can provide an answer. Not only was my re-open request declined but [my edit was rolled back because "it invalidates existing answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278400/volatile-labels#comment128071262_19278400)

---

I understand that this is a very small and niche post topic, but I simply want to save any future searchers the misunderstanding that what they want to do is not possible because of an incorrect answer.

Comment: My only concern would be the SEO of the old post is pretty good (I searched for the exact same string, "volatile labels") so it might be a bit harder to find the correct post. It's more of a nice-to-have but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't fully agree in this situation since the newer post answers the issue pretty completely. I also don't have enough rep yet to post comments :)

Comment: I suppose 3 people could vote to reopen it and then close again against the duplicate but it would be nice if gold badge users could do this (change the close reason to point to a duplicate) themselves. Normally it's not thought to be worth it to re-open just to change a close reason but I think pointing people toward an answer would be a good thing. It's just still going to be hard to convince multiple to give up votes for a question that's ultimately staying closed.

Comment: @BSMP Gold badge holders cannot change the close reason (they can change the dupe-target) and they cannot single-handedly reopen a question that isn't closed as a duplicate. You'll still have to have 3 users (or a mod) to reopen the question.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Yes, I'm saying it'd be nice if they *could* change the close reason to a duplicate.

Comment: And here is FR to "change close reason"... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761/should-we-allow-voting-to-change-the-close-vote-reason-of-a-question ... unlikely to be implemented as it has low votes two mods wrote against it.

Comment: I've handled this case. I'm happy to do so in similar cases. In general, I strongly prefer closing as a duplicate over closing as another reason (such as unclear), even if both fit, for precisely the reason you cite: it is more likely to help future searchers when we refer them to a duplicate. A moderator flag or a Meta post is the best way to get something this fixed. I realize it's a cumbersome process, but it should be rare. You may also be able to ask in a chat room where C users with gold badges hang out, or even in the SOCVR chat room.

Comment: But do pay attention to the duplicates I linked here: don't re-open questions for the purposes of re-closing them for a different reason. That is counter-productive, and it creates a lot more work for everyone. That C question definitely didn't need to be re-opened and answered. As you noted, it's already been answered elsewhere. Answering duplicates is harmful, so we don't do that.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't see how that is a solution in this case. There is already a perfectly good Q&A. The problem here is just that an older question was closed as "unclear", when it would be more useful to everyone to have it closed as a duplicate of the other Q&A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19278400/2) put *a new question* into [Can a label (branch target) be labeled "volatile" to prevent it from being touched by GCC optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278400/volatile-labels) (even if it probably matched the intent of the original post). Such edits are not allowed, especially if the edit invalidates existing answers. Also note that your edit completely drained [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)-juice out of the question by changing the title to remove the text you used to find the question.

What you could do instead:

- Follow [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) to get to 50 points and then add a comment to the original question (I think [one I've added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278400/volatile-labels#comment128186961_19278400) should be enough).
- Ask a new question and either add a comment along the lines of  "this question exists as signpost for [How to tell gcc to keep my unused labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086938/how-to-tell-gcc-to-keep-my-unused-labels), please vote as duplicate" or if (you can) just flag that new question as duplicate (I'm not sure what are conditions when one can vote their own question as duplicate).
- Ask for guidance here as you did.

While I agree that closing the first one as duplicate would make sense we generally don't do that because it requires several people to coordinate changing the close reason see [Should I vote to reopen when I believe the reason for closing no longer applies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262211/should-i-vote-to-reopen-when-i-believe-the-reason-for-closing-no-longer-applies) (and corresponding "Feature-request" - [Should we allow voting to change the close vote reason of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761/should-we-allow-voting-to-change-the-close-vote-reason-of-a-question)). It is possible some diamond mod will find this meta post and decide to change the close reason (as they can do it singlehandedly) or some people with gold C badges agree and coordinate re-opening.