# Why was my question closed as "not reproducible or was caused by typos"?

Tags: support, specific-question

The question can be found here: [Why won't Ansible ever match hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932195/why-wont-ansible-ever-match-hosts)

The reason given was:

> not reproducible or was caused by typos.

I don't understand this reasoning for closing it. I have proofread the question and am not seeing any typos. I also disagree that it is not reproducible. The link to the GitHub is posted in the question along with the sample file of what I am trying to do. I think it would take some effort to set this up, but that is not the same as it not being reproducible.

It also states that the question:

> was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

I don't understand this either as no answer was provided, hence it was never resolved. There were some comments that suggested a resolution, however this did not work.

From what I can tell, I have laid out the problem I am having and explained what I have attempted so far. I have also updated/edited the question as I made progress trying to resolve the problem. I also respectfully engaged with a user in the comments.

Comment: I'd *assume* the closers just cherrypicked "not reproducible" out of the close reason and ignored the rest. I don't think that is the correct close reason, but, regardless, a link to somewhere else where your full project is *is not* a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The key parts that are necessary to diagnose your problem need to exist within the question itself.

Comment: I'm not a subject matter expert, so while I edited the formatting in your question, I'm unable to say what the correct close reason is (between "not reproducible" and "needs debugging details"), or even if there really are enough details in the question to duplicate the problem. One thing that you could try is start a completely new project and put *just* the information/code you've put into the question into that project. Does that new project duplicate the problem? [Note: given that there are multiple hosts, it may require using completely different hosts to verify it can be duplicated.]

Comment: Based on the timing of the comments and the initial close vote, I believe that [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932195/why-wont-ansible-ever-match-hosts#comment133930202_75932195) is intended as an explanation of the "typo" (i.e., that you forgot the rest of the hostname).  Whether this is truly a typo-like error or a misunderstanding that would be a useful question, I can't say for sure as a non-subject matter expert.

Comment: You may want to address "and that is not a question for StackOverflow anymore as your issue probably comes from bad SSH configuration, bad network or anything the like." comment (by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%ce%b2-%ce%b5%ce%b7%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%84-%ce%b2%ce%b5) here. Because irrespective whether original close reason applies to current version of the post or not we [do not re-open](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262211/should-i-vote-to-reopen-when-i-believe-the-reason-for-closing-no-longer-applies) questions that should stay closed.

Comment: @RyanM assumptions are 100% accurate, my close vote is on the premise of the missing `.hunter.lab` in your playbook target. Which I did not retract later because, although the reason of the close vote might have changed (from typo to off-topic for SO; then your further edit bringing a dynamic Azure inventory that was totally absent of the first version of your question made it a totally different question) the question still looked like off topic.

Answer (score 12):

I do not know anything about the technologies you are using here (well, I have some familiarity with YAML as a format, but that's about it); but I like to think I have a pretty good handle on Stack Overflow policy.

In the .yml file, when you wrote

```
hosts: XTOF-WKS,DANY-WKS
```

whereas the hosts file said

```
XTOF-WKS.hunter.lab
DANY-WKS.hunter.lab
```

It's clear that those two things don't match: the names in the .yml file don't have the `.hunter.lab` part. The first comment you got was pointing out this mismatch, and the second suggested that you can also use a `*` wildcard to avoid having to type it all out. But apparently, these shortened forms won't work as-is.

So, the operative question from a Meta standpoint is: **Did you expect them** to work as-is, as a conscious decision on your part, when you created the .yml file?

*If no*: then that is a **classic example of what we mean by a typo**. We take questions about code that is deliberate and that has already been checked over for obvious errors - because any given piece of code can be done wrong in countless "obvious error" sorts of ways (I mistyped the word "error" while trying to write that - twice!), and finding such problems does not *contribute to a searchable Q&A library*. Someone else who happened by chance to have the exact same problem, would not know what to search for, and would likely find lots of irrelevant stuff anyway. (For that matter: search engines nowadays love to try to read your mind, even when you explicitly tell them not to, and part of that process involves correcting spelling errors.)

*If yes*: then **that is the core of your real question** - "why can't I write the .yml file this way?". However, this means the question is **unclear** - you aren't actually *asking* that, we have to infer it. Even then, that inference is based on an assumption that you know what to write instead - you certainly didn't give any such indication.

However, based on how you've written the "edits" to your question, I'm leaning towards the former interpretation. And a problem that is caused by a typo, means the question is "not reproducible or caused by typos".

As a side note: edits should **actually edit the question, not update it**. If you try doing something new based on suggestions in the comments, and run into a *different problem*, then you now have a *different question*. On the other hand, if you realized a mistake in posting the code, but didn't actually have that error locally (or figured it out before posting), then that is something to fix by editing *to change the code, as if nothing ever happened*. We don't want remarks like "edit" or "update" in questions here, because they don't make for clear, coherent questions that can be understood all at once. Again, the goal here is to build a *searchable Q&A library*. Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**.

Moving on:

> I don't understand this either as no answer was provided, hence it was never resolved.

The phrasing for the message is set by the system. We can't change the wording. That said, answers on Stack Overflow are **not primarily about resolving the problem that OP encountered** - they're, again, about contributing to a searchable Q&A library. The flip side of that is that the problem *absolutely can* be resolved without an answer. If you do what the comments say and then realize that there wasn't a useful question, for example.

Aside from that, you imply something absurd here. **The point** of closing questions on Stack Overflow is to *prevent new answers from coming in* while the question is not in a proper, answerable state. A typo certainly qualifies for that, because we don't want to publish Q&A about typos, because it is not at all useful. But if your standard for closing questions a typos is "there has to be an answer, so that the problem can be 'resolved' (in a way not less likely to help future readers)", that defeats the entire purpose.

> There were some comments that suggested a resolution, however this did not work.

Again: you encountered a **new problem**. The comments *did* resolve the problem *that you were asking about*. You don't get to make posts here that are about making a project work, and go back and forth with us until the project works: you post *questions* that are about *one specific* problem; and if they are suitable for site, you get actual answers in the answer section - otherwise, we try to be helpful and nice, but we reject the question. We do this because **Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum**, and we want questions that *contribute to a searchable Q&A library*. A back-and-forth discussion *fundamentally can't do that*, especially when the two sides of the discussion are physically separated into a supposed "question" and "answer". Just imagine how that feels for everyone who comes across the post later with a search engine.

That said, your new problem seems to be **not reproducible** (we don't have your SSH configuration; we probably don't have access rights to try connecting to the servers you want to use; for all we know the servers could have just been *temporarily* down, etc. etc. etc.) and **not about programming** ("why can't I connect to a server" is not a question about programming, because there most likely isn't a *fault in code that you wrote* that is causing the connection problem).

Moving on:

> From what I can tell, I have laid out the problem I am having and explained what I have attempted so far. I have also updated/edited the question as I made progress trying to resolve the problem. I also respectfully engaged with a user in the comments.

That is all well and good. However, **no amount of "doing the right thing" can turn an off-topic question into an on-topic question**. Clearly laying out the problem doesn't matter if the problem is caused by a typo. Explaining what you tried doesn't matter if the correct thing to try is something you knew about and overlooked. (It's also not usually that useful: we want this information *so that we can understand the question better, not* to so you can prove you "deserve" an answer.) Updates are counterproductive unless they are **clarifying an existing question** - we don't want updates on your progress on making the project work, because the question is **about the code, not you or your project**. Engaging respectfully is simply expected, and gains you no extra credit: it just means that you don't get talked to for Code of Conduct violations.

Comment: As the first close voter and the one posting those comments, I 100% relate. The only possible thing missing out of your answer is the fact that retracting a vote on SO makes it impossible to re-cast a close vote, and this is the reason I did not retract my first close vote, although the reason of the close might have changed due to further comments/edits.