# Why is my question still being closed after I've explained why it is not a duplicate?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I had this question ([Sprite jumping around in a undesirable way when handling collision while flipping the sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304074)) which was marked as a duplicate of three questions and was closed.

I edited the question and explained that it was not a duplicate. Two of the questions that my question was marked as a duplicate of, were actually questions that I did not ask, and my code had already solved those problems.

Why would I ask a question that I already had an answer to?

And for the other question ([Pygame: Weird sprite offset when flipped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599854/)), it only explained why a problem arose, and I knew this already as well, and it was while handling this problem, I've started getting some undesired behavior. There was an alternative solution provided in the comments to combat this, but I've explained why it can't be used in my code.

Comment: Reopening is a manual process and will take a while until people have looked at and voted on your question. FWIW, you may want to take the time to further improve your question. For example, the code *in the question itself* is not sufficient to replicate the issue – linking to a huge repo is not sufficient. The description of what you are actually asking is also rather hard to make out; as far as I can tell it's "But this doesn't seem to work." (the rest seem to be things that do work or aren't asked about) which doesn't tell us much. [...]

Comment: [...] You may want to re-read the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and other help pages. If you need to refer to lines 298 and 445 in some off-site code, this is not useful for both volunteers to answer nor for others with similar problems.

Comment: I see a lot, a lot a lot a lot of nested if/else statements in your code. As in: you're winging it yourself. I take it that PyGame does not really have any kind of built-in support for physics models which would include collision detection? If this is the case then the PyGame part of your question is a bit of a red herring. Implementing collision detection properly is really hard (believe me, I know) and it depends very much on how you model your data. Your code doesn't even really show if your game has animations or not, you only speak of a "sprite". Ambiguous at best.

Comment: This is a [meta-tag:specific-question] post; it should not be closed as a duplicate of a generic/non-specific FAQ.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question is still missing the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and as result still has to be closed. While it is possible that "duplicate" reason does not apply, we do not re-open questions that should be closed just because close reason is not the most fitting - [Should I vote to reopen when I believe the reason for closing no longer applies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262211/should-i-vote-to-reopen-when-i-believe-the-reason-for-closing-no-longer-applies).

Things to improve the question so it can be possibly re-opened:

- make sure all necessary data and code present in the question. It sounds like you have unconventional sprites (that have bigger hit-boxes than necessary) - it is likely you need to put *representative* images into the question (ideally you create *sample* images for that i.e. with solid squares/circles instead of your custom art, make sure problem indeed happen for those images). Don't forget to include exact values for all coordinates. Limit number of involved objects (likely need just one for the object and one for the obstacle).
- change style of mentioning of duplicates from "this is not duplicate" to "I tried following {link to the question} but it did not work because ...". The reason is when/if question is re-opened the linked duplicates will only be available in the history and the remaining question should read as single standalone post ("duplicate" would have no meaning/link when question is open).

Note that re-open is potentially long process as several (3+) people need to see the post in the "reopen" queue and vote on that. You can see progress of that in the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77304074/timeline) by clicking on "clock" icon next to the post.

PS: thanks for taking the effort to edit the post and ask for clarifications. Remember that asking good questions is hard - don't get stats of older posts to discourage your efforts as downvoted questions are automatically deleted leaving impression that everyone else only ask ok questions.

Comment: I thought that questions are reviewed for re-open based on the provided reason, thanks for the clarification.  For the minimal reproducible example, I honestly don't know how I can make reproduce that without including a lot of code, at which point, I felt it would be easier to work with directly from the repo. But I do understand, if my question is closed for that reason.

Answer (score 7):

I can't address the contents of the post since it is really not my experience, but I can explain what is happening "between the scenes":

- A trusted user with a [pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pygame) gold badge unilaterally closed your question as a duplicate. Since users with gold badges are supposedly domain experts on the subject, as well as veteran users of the site, they are trusted to do this without the need for consensus with other experienced users doing volunteer moderation.
- After closing they added several target links, either because they were trying to be helpful by providing extra information, or possibly because there were multiple things in your question they considered as duplicates to different posts.
- Once a question is closed, none can answer it and the poster is then given a chance to edit it into shape.
- After your edits yesterday, the post entered the re-open review queue, where consensus of several users is required to re-open it. These users will not just review the close reason (duplicate) but also if there are other problems with the question making it difficult to understand and answer. They may either conclude that the question should be re-opened or that it should remain closed.

  Alternatively, another [pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pygame)  gold badge holder spotting the question could unilaterally re-open it without the need for review queues, if they disagree that it is a duplicate.
- Notably, far from all volunteer re-open reviewers will have domain expertise of Pygame, so many of them will probably skip the review and leave it until someone with relevant knowledge comes along.
- The re-open review queue currently sits at 194 questions still in review. That's a lot of review work and volunteer user moderators as well as actual moderators (those with a diamond next to their user name) are in decline and overwhelmed with work. One of the many reasons for this is a volunteer strike held this summer where moderators and other volunteers simply refused to do any work due to the Stack Overflow company's policies regarding AI generated content and other things.

  So don't expect this to happen swiftly.

The best you can do in the meantime is trying to edit the post further into shape by following the advice given in comments to the post and here in this meta thread by @Alexei Levenkov and others.