# Does "I tried external tool T" turns a question into requesting external libraries/tools automatically?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, recommendation-questions

So I came across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74026656/convert-word-doc-to-html-programmatically-in-ios-swift, which is currently closed as seeking recommendations of tools, but I think this reason is a bit weird. As I understand, the question part is asking like "what is other ways to do this?", which uses the words "other ways" instead of "other libraries/tools", which doesn't ask suggesting another external tools to complete the task directly.

Does "I tried external library L to do x but not working" ruins "What is the other way to do x?" into recommendations of tools automatically?

Note: It is just think the close reason is weird, doesn't suggest if this question is valid or not.

Comment: Usual note: we [don't re-open questions that are closed for slightly wrong reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262211/should-i-vote-to-reopen-when-i-believe-the-reason-for-closing-no-longer-applies). This explains why the question stays closed even if it is not the ideal close reason.

Comment: Given said "we don't reopen questions" policy, it should be as good as it can be right from the get-go. Wrong close reasons send out wrong signals. So good for you that you care about it. But don't expect others to have the same amount of care. People nowadays close fast, not well.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the question? Users (with the exception of diamond moderators and you) cannot see it without having 10K reputation. Thank you!

Comment: While it might be the right close reason the question lacks effort, clarity and detail which would be enough to close it.

Answer (score 20):

In the general case, no, stating that you tried to use an external tool / library etc. does not make the question a recommendation question.

The specific question here though falls right between "lacking focus" and being a "recommendation question".

If one considers that question to be a how-to question, it lacks focus because the solving the problem involves multiple steps that could be Q&A pairs of their own. Some of those steps would be:

- Parsing the Word document with all of the styling, text, images, etc. (This could be further broken down since a word documents structure can be quite complicated),
- Taking the parsed document and creating HTML out of it (Again this can be broken down and lacks focus on its own)

Given writing code to solve the problem without any external tool / library would lack focus people naturally think about using tools / libraries to answer such questions. Users following this train of thought then close the question for being a recommendation question.

In the end although the question isn't explicitly asking for tool / library recommendations, I'd close it for lacking focus. Given it is already closed though, reopening it just to close it again isn't very useful.